# How to make a RadioButton look like regular Button in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm implementing a toolbox-like pane, so user can only pick one tool at a time, and I switched from `Button` to `RadioButton` for its behavior.

But I found that `RadioButton` uses its own skin with a dot, however I still want it to display like a normal `Button`. I'm a beginner with JavaFX and FXML, so anyone know how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Use a [`ToggleButton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ToggleButton.html)

Comment: @James_D However the behavior I need is that of a `RadioButton`, i.e. clicking on a selected one will not cancel its selection, etc.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that difference in behavior. (Are there others?) You could either refer to the [default style sheet](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u60/rt/file/996511a322b7/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css) to override the skin of the radio button, which is a bit of work but a pretty robust way to do it, or just register enough event filters to fix the behavior the way you want.

Comment: Try adding the `buttonStyleClass`

Comment: See: [Preventing ToggleButton from being unselected when in ToggleGroup](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2401440?tstart=0)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First Create a **radio button,** remove the `radio-button` style and then add the `toggle-button` style like

```
RadioButton radioButton=new RadioButton("Radio");
radioButton.getStyleClass().remove("radio-button");
radioButton.getStyleClass().add("toggle-button");
```

Hope that solves your problem

Comment: I tried to add 'toggle-button' as style, but I cannot get rid of the dot of `RadioButton`.

Comment: @DreaminginCode Check out the code edit,It now works perfectly fine.

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me. But still I want to handle it in FXML. Simply using styleClass="toggle-button" won't remove "radio-button" class, do you have any solution?

Comment: Your solution answers the question directly, so I'm accepting it for future visitors now.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I went with another way around. You can extend `ToggleButton` so that it behaves like a `RadioButton`. This does not have the weird click effect of consuming mouse release.

```
public class RadioToggleButton extends ToggleButton {

    // As in RadioButton.
    /**
     * Toggles the state of the radio button if and only if the RadioButton
     * has not already selected or is not part of a {@link ToggleGroup}.
     */
    @Override
    public void fire() {
        // we don't toggle from selected to not selected if part of a group
        if (getToggleGroup() == null || !isSelected()) {
            super.fire();
        }
    }
}
```

Then in FXML:

```
<fx:define>
    <ToggleGroup fx:id="toolToggleGroup" />
</fx:define>
<RadioToggleButton toggleGroup="$toolToggleGroup" />
<RadioToggleButton toggleGroup="$toolToggleGroup" />
```

And it is done.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the style you can use to get rid of the dot

```
.radio-button > .radio {
  -fx-background-color: transparent;
  -fx-background-insets: 0;
  -fx-background-radius: 0px;
  -fx-padding: 0.0em; /* 4 8 4 8 */
}
.radio-button:selected > .radio > .dot {
  -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

Documenting here; in case someone finds it useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ToggleButton` and `ToggleGroup`, but you have to create an extension of `ToggleGroup` to keep the selected one selected. Here's an [example](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2290865?tstart=0).

Comment: But I think the buttons in this scenario are semantically `RadioButton`s instead of `ToggleButton`s. Do you know any way to style the `RadioButton` as `ToggleButton`?

Comment: A `ToggleGroup` implemented in the manner stated in the link will act like `RadioButton` in that they will only allow one to be selected at a time, and the selection is persistent. So, if you click a selected `ToggleButton`, it will not deselect. If you click a different `ToggleButton` in the group, the new one will become selected, and the old one will deselect. Isn't that the behavior you desire?

Comment: I wanted the semantic correctness of `RadioButton`, but now I admit that a `RadioButton` also carries its appearance in its semantics. I'm now using another solution posted here myself instead of the link you provided, but thank you for your help.