# bind two ToggleButtons to a BooleanProperty

Tags: java, javafx, properties

I have two ToggleButtons and I would like them both to be bound to a Boolean property so that when one ToggleButton is selected, the other ToggleButton isn't, and the BooleanProperty is true, and vice versa.

Here's what I tried.

FXML file:

```
<VBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="my.package.MainController" styleClass="Tool" fx:id="root">
<HBox spacing="10">
    <fx:define>
        <ToggleGroup fx:id="modeToggleGroup"/>
    </fx:define>
    <ToggleButton fx:id="manualModeBtn" text="Manual Mode" selected="true" toggleGroup="$modeToggleGroup"/>
    <ToggleButton fx:id="automaticModeBtn" text="Automatic Mode" toggleGroup="$modeToggleGroup"/>
</HBox>
<!-- other stuff -->
</VBox>
```

Controller file:

```
public class MainController {

    @FXML
    private ToggleButton manualModeBtn;
    @FXML
    private ToggleButton automaticModeBtn;

    private BooleanProperty isAutomaticMode;

    public void initialize() {
        isAutomaticMode = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
        automaticModeBtn.selectedProperty.bindBidirectional(isAutomaticMode);
    }
}
```

The ToggleGroup ensures that neither button is selected at the same time, but I can still unselect both of them, which I don't want to be possible.

How do I bind the other ToggleButton to the opposite (i.e. `not()`) of the Boolean Property?

Comment: Can you just use `RadioButton`s instead? Those have exactly that functionality.

Comment: I could, but I'm actually using the controlsfx `SegmentedButton`s (https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/SegmentedButton.html)  which look really nice and I'd like to keep that look. It would be a lot more effort than it's worth to style RadioButtons to look how I want them to. If there's an easier solution that isn't too hackish, I'd rather use that.

Comment: I don't really like the "feel" of unchecking a toggle button and the other toggle button getting selected. TBH I'd just use a single checkbox here... is either automatic, or it's not.

Comment: That's fair. I originally had a checkbox, and I may go back to it, but I wanted to try this.

Comment: Seems like it is pretty easy to make a radio button look like a toggle button: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33786146/how-to-make-a-radiobutton-look-like-regular-button-in-javafx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this by using listeners:

```
public class MainController {

    @FXML
    private ToggleButton manualModeBtn;
    @FXML
    private ToggleButton automaticModeBtn;


    public void initialize() {
        manualModeBtn.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> automaticModeBtn.setSelected(! isNowSelected));
        automaticModeBtn.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> manualModeBtn.setSelected(! isNowSelected));

    }
}
```

Note that `RadioButton` has almost this functionality already (in the case of a radio button, you can't "deselect" it), so  you could simply use `RadioButton`s instead. Note [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33786146/how-to-make-a-radiobutton-look-like-regular-button-in-javafx), if it is just a case of how they look.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done by setting a listener on the `ToggleGroup's` `selectedToggleProperty`.

You first have to set an initial button.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ToggleButtonExperiments extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        primaryStage.setTitle("HBox Experiment 1");

        ToggleButton toggleButton1 = new ToggleButton("Left");
        ToggleButton toggleButton2 = new ToggleButton("Right");

        ToggleGroup toggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();
        toggleButton1.setSelected(true);//set initial button!!!!!

        toggleGroup.selectedToggleProperty().addListener((obs, oldTog, newTog) -> {
            if (newTog == null) {
                oldTog.setSelected(true);
            }
        });

        toggleButton1.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
        toggleButton2.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);

        HBox hbox = new HBox(toggleButton1, toggleButton2);

        Scene scene = new Scene(hbox, 200, 100);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```