# Active Button in Navigation Bar (JavaFX)

Tags: css, javafx, sidebar, navigationbar

I am beginer with javafx and css. I am currently creating a Navigation Bar in JavaFX. Like web design, it will use hover when the mouse glides and active to make buttons in the sidebar to help users know which scenes they are. However, I could only do Hover, when I chose a scene, then manipulated on that scene, the buttons in the sidebar would be the same, so users do not know which scenes they are.
Can CSS in JavaFX do that or need to create class for that?

Now:[My sideBar now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AK3G.png)
And CSS now:

```
.sideBar {
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-background-color: TRANSPARENT;
}
.sideBar:hover,
.sideBar:focused {
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-background-color: TRANSPARENT;
    -fx-border-color: #bfeafc;
    -fx-border-width: 0 0 0 5;
}
```

I expect to:[We'll know we are in Search Scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZxY5.png)

Comment: Consider using `ToggleButton`s instead of `Button`s and style their `:selected` state.

Comment: The new problem has come. When I choose another scene, the old scene needs to lose Selected, but not. What do I need?

Comment: If you use `ToggleButton`s, put them all in the same `ToggleGroup`. Then only one can be selected at once. The [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ToggleButton.html) shows how to do this. Create and post a [mre] if you can't get it to work.

Comment: Perhaps use a [RadioButton made to look like a ToggleButton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33796837/1155209).  From the ToggleButton documentation: "Unlike RadioButtons, ToggleButtons in a ToggleGroup do not attempt to force at least one selected ToggleButton in the group. That is, if a ToggleButton is selected, clicking on it will cause it to become unselected. With RadioButton, clicking on the selected button in the group will have no effect."  I think the RadioButton behavior might be closer to what you want.

Comment: Similar [example using hyperlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556637/how-to-have-menus-website-style-navigation-links-in-java-desktop-application/13574231#13574231), which can also use graphics if set on the links, but perhaps the toggle/radio button-based solutions might be more appropriate.